# Integrating Angular with googlemaps

Tags: javascript, angular, google-maps

I'm using [**angular-googlemaps(agm)**](https://github.com/SebastianM/angular-google-maps) and it's working so far..

But I want to search an address by latitude and longitude, so I found part of the solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804388/how-to-get-full-address-from-latitude-longitude-in-angular-2#answer-42283369)... the problem is:

I followed the following steps:

1 - Installed googlemaps: `yarn add @types/googlemaps -D`

2 - Import googlemaps in my component: `import { } from 'googlemaps';`

And when I try to do anything with `"google"` like this, for example:

```
const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
```

I get the following error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: google is not defined

1st. attempt: Declare `google` this way in my component:

```
declare var google: any;
```

2nd. attempt: Put `googlemaps` inside `types` in `tsconfig.app.json` (angular-cli):

```
...
"types": ["googlemaps"]
...
```

But the error keeps appearing.

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try `import * as google from 'googlemaps';`?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the answer you want but as a work around you can use their api :

```
const location = { longitude, latitude, accuracy };
const baseUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?";

const url = `${this.baseUrl}latlng=${latitude},${longitude}&key=${API_KEY}`
this.http.get(url).subscribe(r => console.log(r));
```